# Modulo of an arithmetic expression

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have a bucket of elements, the amount of elements $E$  is given by this equation, with constraints on parameters $S_A$ and $S_B$:

$$
\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{3} 
 E_0 = (4-S_{A}) + 4*N + S_{B} \\
 S_{A} < 4 ; S_{A} \in N\\
 S_{B} < 4 ; S_{B} \in N\\
 S_A > S_B
\end{alignedat}
\right.
\end{equation*}
$$

I pick these elements 4 at a time, so that after $n$ times $E_n = E_0 - 4*n $  until I can't do it anymore because $E_{N} < 4$, after picking them N times.

How do I find an expression for the remaining elements $E_N$?

I know that the operation to do is the modulo one, but I can't come up with an expression:

$$ E_N = E_0 \mod 4 $$
$$ E_N = [ (4-S_{A}) + 4*N + S_{B}] \mod 4 $$
$$ E_N = ( 4 - S_A + S_B ) \mod 4 $$

And I can't simplify anymore. I would like to reach an expression that has not the modulo in it.

Is it possible?

Since I need to use it in code where calculating the modulo is not an option, I can create a lookup table which is doable because the $S_A,S_B$ are small values, however finding an expression would be beautiful.

```
LUT = lambda sa,sb:(4-sa+sb)%4
for sb in range(4):
     for sa in range(4):
             if(sa>sb): 
                     print(f"f({sa},{sb}) -> {LUT(sa,sb)}")
```

```
f(1,0) -> 3
f(2,0) -> 2
f(3,0) -> 1
f(2,1) -> 3
f(3,1) -> 2
f(3,2) -> 3
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure what you are after.  You want to know  remainder of $E_0$ on division by $4$?  But that's clearly $4-S_A+S_B$.  Which, I think, is what you wrote.  What else do you want?

Comment: Thanks @lulu, you are right, this is valid if the constrain $S_A > S_B$, and I thank you for that because that's exactly my case. If the constrain is lifted this is no longer true. How would I find an expression for that (without `mod` in the expression)? Is it possible?

Comment: @lulu if $S_A = 0, S_B=2$ then $(4-S_A+S_B) \neq [(4-S_A+S_B)\mod4]$ because $6 \neq 2$

Comment: You can't have $S_A=0. S_B=2$.  you specified that $S_A>S_B$.  If you want to drop that condition, then of course the rule is different.

Comment: @lulu I addressed that, I asked what if the constrain is lifted. Also, how did you see that the modulo was already reduced? I am interested in your thought process.

Comment: Your expression, with the constraints is $4+(S_B-S_A)$.  The constraints assure us that $-3≤S_B-S_A<0$

Comment: @lulu this is eye opening. Thanks a million.

Comment: Absent the constraints, I don't think there's a lot to say.  The answer is the least possible natural number congruent to $4-S_A+S_B$ but there's no universal way to know what that is.

Comment: @lulu thanks, I just wanted to know if there was a way to derive an expression. I am fine saying that there is not one.